# Is there a way to know the functioning of the event queue in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, eventqueue

```py
from time import time
import pygame
pygame.init()

t = time()

Events = pygame.event.get()
print(Events)

end = False

while not end:
    if time()-t>3:
        print(Events)
        Events = pygame.event.get()
        t = time()
```

I wrote the following to know about the event queue in pygame.
Here I am waiting for three seconds until the next `event.get()` is called and in these 3 seconds, I do a lot of events through my keyboard and mouse,

**But still I see a blank event queue in the next print**...

Why is it so because if I am not wrong, pygame queues all the events that happen and `event.get()` returns us the queue and then clears it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Pygame window to get the IO events for the keyboard and mouse:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

end = False
while not end:
    clock.tick(1)

    events = pygame.event.get()
    if events:
        print(events)

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            end = True

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: @Prakhar `tick` reduces the frames per second. You can remove it or changed it e.g. `tick(100)`. Without `tick` you'll use 100% cpu. See [`tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick). I'm using `pygame.time.Clock.tick` instead of `time`. Pygame is based on SDL2. The event handling is related to the application window (at least for the IO events).